# IntelliJ cannot import class "fasterxml"

Tags: java, json, scala, fasterxml

I have just started learning scala in Intellij and am trying to work with JSON files. I'm not able to use the following imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
```

The error I'm getting is:

`object fasterxml is not a member of package com`

[image: error]

How do I fix this error and successfully import the module?

Comment: You will need to add the fasterxml dependencies to your build.sbt file.

Comment: Yes, few people told me that. I have tried adding the following lines in my build.sbt file:

`libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.2"`

`libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.11.0"`

These didn't help. Getting same errors. How do I correctly add dependencies? Also, do I need to download any jar files for this?